# Create two way table by multiple columns

Tags: r

I have data as below. I want to create a two way table and I can easily create it.

```
start_city=c("a","b","a")
end_city=c("b","a","a")
travel=data.frame(start_city,end_city)
table(start_city,end_city)
```

Now I would like to add a state in my two way table. How could I do the same

```
start_city=c("a","b","a")
end_city=c("b","a","a")
start_state=c("x","y","x")
end_state=c("y","x","x")
travel=data.frame(start_city,start_state,end_city,end_state)
```

## update1

`table(do.call(paste, travel[1:2]), do.call(paste, travel[3:4]))` 
given by akrun below works.
But, in the resulting data frame is there an easy way to separate content of the leftmost column and the top column by a `,`? Right now the leftmost column and the top column have concatenation of state and city.

Comment: Do you want `table(do.call(paste, travel[1:2]), do.call(paste, travel[3:4]))`

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found this package. This serves similar to three-way table in SAS PROC FREQ. Hope this helps.

```
source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")
crosstab(travel, row.vars = c("start_state", "start_city"), col.vars = c("end_state","end_city"), type = "f")
```